# Refresh Kendo grid without page loading-Asp.net-MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using following code to load kendo grid that contains user details.

1. An 'Add User' button click opens a partial view on the grid , where a new user is added.
2. when user is added is successfully the view closed and the grid is refreshed.

My problem is the way I have loaded the grid once the user is added the whole page is refreshed and thus the grid.

I just want refresh the grid and not the whole page.

Code:

cshtml:

```
<div>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<AllocatedUsers>().ToolBar(toolBar =>      toolBar.Template(
    @<text>
        <div class="grid-top-control" style="margin:5px">
            <button id="addUser" class="k-button">Add User</button>        
        </div>


    </text>))
        .Name("CWUserCreationGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.UserLoggIn)
              .Width(240);
            columns.Bound(c => c.RoleName).Width(190);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ParentName);

        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
                .BindTo((IEnumerable<AllocatedUsers>)ViewData["CWUserAllocatedList"]
```

)
    )

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetCWUserCreationTab()
    {         

        List<AllocatedUsersModel> LstAllocatedUsersModel = new List<AllocatedUsersModel>();
        var Users = _UserManager.GetAllocatedUsers(UserContext.UserId);

        if (UserContext.userType == 1)
        {
            Users = Users.Where(x => int.Parse(x.ParentID) == UserContext.UserId).ToList();
        }
        ViewData["CWUserAllocatedList"] = Users;

        return PartialView("_CWUserCreationTab");
    }
```

To refresh the grid:

```
$('#CWUserCreationGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
```

Comment: you'd have to add Ajax datasource binding in there somewhere.. You can't do this if you're binding to a collection in ViewData[]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using the ViewData binding method vs. Ajax?